# Passport authenticate doesn't return an express-compatible type in Typescript express app

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js

I'm trying to use passport.authenticate as a middleware function in my Typescript Express app:

`router.get('/spotify', passport.authenticate('spotify'))`

passport.authenticate here returns as a Typescript 'any' type, presumably to guarantee compatibility with multiple HTTP server frameworks. The when debugging, the function signature however matches the RequestHandler definition that Express uses.

Because authenticate returns as 'any' type, typescript-eslint reports an error (no-unsafe-argument) because I'm assigning an 'any' variable to a RequestHandler parameter. This can be circumvented by asserting the type of authenticate as RequestHandler. But as far as I'm aware, type assertion is a bad practice.

I've tried type narrowing, but as far as I'm aware it's impossible to type narrow an 'any' variable to a function.

Is the only other way using the framework method included in the Authenticator interface? This seems quite a bit more complicated for a seemingly simple task.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this and what worked for me was to force the `RequestHandler` type. So to apply that to your code that would be

```
import { RequestHandler} from 'express';

router.get(
  '/spotify',
  passport.authenticate('spotify') as RequestHandler
);
```